# Como exportar todas las graficas de un libro de excel a powerpoint con python?

Tags: python

Soy nuevo con python y se requiere exportar todas imagenes de un libro de excel a powerpoint. Mi pregunta es como puedo hacerlo. Este codigo graba en powerpoint las hojas en blanco.

```
import openpyxl
from pptx import Presentation 
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('prueba.xlsm')
hojas = wb.sheetnames
prs=Presentation()
for hoja in hojas:
    sheet = wb[hoja]
    shapes = sheet._images
    if shapes:
        print("Shapes in the sheet:")
        for shape in shapes:
            print("- ")
            slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[0])
    else:
        print("No shapes in the sheet")
prs.save('ESPecial.pptx')
wb.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

puedes usar el método `add_picture()` del objeto `shapes` de la diapositiva, aqui te muestro un ejemplo

```
import openpyxl
from pptx import Presentation 
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('prueba.xlsm')
hojas = wb.sheetnames
prs=Presentation()
for hoja in hojas:
    sheet = wb[hoja]
    shapes = sheet._images
    if shapes:
        slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[0])
        for shape in shapes:
            image = shape.image
            left = shape.left
            top = shape.top
            width = shape.width
            height = shape.height
            slide.shapes.add_picture(image, left, top, width, height) #  Aqui aplico el add_picture 
    else:
        print("No shapes in the sheet")

prs.save('ESPecial.pptx')
wb.close()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Pero se genera un error: AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'image'. El archivo si tiene imagenes en las primeras 2 hojas.